# Login via xrdp session doesn't register as logged-on user

Tags: log, remote-login

When I open a xrdp session (xorg) to my Linux system and check for existing user logins via `who` or `last`, there is no entry for the xrdp session. Why is that? And is there a way to show current and/or past xrdp user logins?

Note: Currently, as a workaround, I use `sudo lsof -w -c xrdp-chan` to check for open sessions

Comment: I'm having exactly the same question. Guess this is not only related to Ubuntu, but to any Linux distro with xrdp.